# Why does borrow checker complain about the lifetimes of these different slices?

Tags: vector, rust, slice, lifetime, borrow-checker

Why, in the code below, does using an array slice work, but using a slice of a `Vec` doesn't?

```rust
use rand::{rngs::adapter::ReadRng, RngCore};
use std::io::Read;

struct MyRng {
    rng: Box<dyn RngCore>,
}

pub fn main() {
    // Version 1: error
    //
    let data = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let data_slice = data.as_slice();

    // Version 2: works
    //
    // let data_slice = &[0_u8][..];

    // Version 3: error (!?!)
    //
    // let data = [0_u8];
    // let data_slice = &data[..];

    let read = Box::new(data_slice) as Box<dyn Read>;
    let rng = Box::new(ReadRng::new(read));

    // With this commented out, all versions work.
    MyRng { rng };
}
```

There are a few things that puzzle me:

- What's the difference between the three approaches, if all are in the same scope?
- The error says that `data` is dropped while borrowed, but points to the end of the scope - isn't everything dropped by then?
- Why if I remove the `MyRng` instantiation, everything works fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Rust Reference on Lifetime Elision:](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes)

> If the trait has no lifetime bounds, then the lifetime is inferred in expressions and is `'static` outside of expressions.

So by default boxed trait objects get a `'static` bound. So this struct:

```rust
struct MyRng {
    rng: Box<dyn RngCore>,
}
```

Actually expands to this:

```rust
struct MyRng {
    rng: Box<dyn RngCore + 'static>,
}
```

Which forces you to produce either an owned type or a `'static` reference in order to satisfy the bound. However, you can opt out of the implicit `'static` bound entirely by making your struct generic, after which all the different versions of the code compile:

```rust
use rand::{rngs::adapter::ReadRng, RngCore};
use std::io::Read;

struct MyRng<'a> {
    rng: Box<dyn RngCore + 'a>,
}

pub fn main() {
    // Version 1: now works
    let data = Vec::<u8>::new();
    let data_slice = data.as_slice();
    let read = Box::new(data_slice) as Box<dyn Read>;
    let rng = Box::new(ReadRng::new(read));
    let my_rng = MyRng { rng };

    // Version 2: still works
    let data_slice = &[0_u8][..];
    let read = Box::new(data_slice) as Box<dyn Read>;
    let rng = Box::new(ReadRng::new(read));
    let my_rng = MyRng { rng };

    // Version 3: now works
    let data = [0_u8];
    let data_slice = &data[..];
    let read = Box::new(data_slice) as Box<dyn Read>;
    let rng = Box::new(ReadRng::new(read));
    let my_rng = MyRng { rng };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b8ef873eb4821647f30271ee5f91430d)

---

To answer your individual questions more directly:

> What's the difference between the three approaches, if all are in the same scope?

Scope and lifetimes aren't the same thing, but the main difference between the 3 approaches is that approach #2 creates a static slice. When you hardcode some `&T` reference into your code without it referring to any data owned by any variable then it gets written into the read-only segment of the binary and gets a `'static` lifetime.

> The error says that data is dropped while borrowed, but points to the end of the scope - isn't everything dropped by then?

Yes, but your type, by definition, requires the passed value to be bounded by a `'static` lifetime, and since approaches #1 and #3 do not produce such values the compiler rejects the code.

> Why if I remove the `MyRng` instantiation, everything works fine?

Because there's nothing wrong with the definition of your `MyRng` struct, only when you try to instantiate it incorrectly does the compiler complain.

Answer (score 1):

`[0_u8]` is a constant, so it undergoes [rvalue static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html), allowing references to it to have a static lifetime, so it won't be dropped. Your code fails because you have a slice that borrows the local variable `data` yet tries to create a `MyRng` variable from it.